# How do I apply a Taylor expansion of this?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given
$$\frac{1}{r}\left(1+\frac{2\epsilon \cos\theta}{r}\right)^{-1/2}$$
I was told by using Taylor expansion I could get
$$1-\frac{2\epsilon \cos\theta}{r}$$ with term of order $\epsilon^2$.
Can someone explain to me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's wrong.
$$ \dfrac{1}{r} \left( 1 + \dfrac{2\epsilon \cos(\theta)}{r}\right)^{-1/2} =  \dfrac{1}{r} - \dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{r^2} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$$
That comes from the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series):
$$ (1 + x)^p = 1 + p x + O(x^2)$$